# Airflow DAG Scheduling for end of month

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to run a schedule on Airflow (v1.9.0).
My DAG needs to run at every end of month, but I don't know how to write the settings.

```py
my_dag = DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID,
             catchup=False,
             default_args=default_args,
             schedule_interval='30 0 31 * *',
             start_date=datetime(2019, 7, 1))
```

But this won't work in a month where there's no 31st, right?
How can I write a `schedule_interval` to run at every end of the month?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by putting `L` in the month position of your `schedule_interval` cron expression.

```py
schedule_interval='59 23 L * *' # 23:59 on the last day of the month
```

Comment: It's work but why ?.
I not see in airflow documentation.

Comment: @GilmarVaz this is [cron syntax](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/cloud-manager-2-5/ncm-reference/data/bexyssf.html)